# How can I get IE7 to see an HTC file in the same directory as my CSS?

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7, directory-structure, html-components

The web design company I work for has a development side, and a published side for their client sites. For dev sites, the CSS is stored in a directory such as `/software-1.5/templates/099/themes/theme-name/theme.css` with `PIE.htc` stored in the same directory. The index page (and all other pages) are stored in the `/software-1.5/` directory. However, once the site is published, the `templates/099/...` part will change to something else.

When I use `behavior: url('PIE.htc')` in my `theme.css` file, IE7 apparently tries to find the HTC file in the base directory, and **not** the CSS directory. How can I make IE7 look for the PIE.htc file in the same directory as the CSS?

Comment: `behavior: url('myCSSFolder/PIE.htc')`?

Comment: IE looks for htc files relative to the HTML file, rather than the CSS file. As such, it’s a pain in the arse.

Comment: So that's it? I'll have to provide the exact path no matter what? No fix at all? I hate IE. I really do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe it does help if you're setting the behavior not within the CSS but within the HTML page in the head section. I don't know of a possibility to make IE use the path of the CSS.